# How to get the Count or Key of TempData in another ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am setting the value of TempData in one ActionResult of different controller and trying to get their Keys of just counts in another controller's ActionResult

```
public ActionResult DealProducts(FormCollection form)
{
   TempData["check"] = "DealUpdated";
}
```

*in another controller*

```
public ActionResult CustomizedBudget()
{
   var temp = TempData["doc"];
   var temp = TempData["doc"].Key;//like this
   if (temp.Count > 0) // or trying to get like this, but not  
}
```

Comment: `TempData.ContainsKey("doc")`?

Comment: It's uncleared, what you trying to do!

Comment: where to get the Value of my TempData `DealUpdated`

Comment: @Qadeer so you want to use `TempData["check"]` in `CustomizedBudget` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Assign

```
public ActionResult DealProducts(FormCollection form)
{
   TempData["check"] = "DealUpdated";
}
```

In CSHTML

```
@{
    TempData.Keep("check");
}
```

in another controller

```
public ActionResult CustomizedBudget()
{
   var count = TempData.Keys.Count;
   var DealUpdatedValue = TempData["check"];
}
```

Comment: where to get the Value of my TempData `DealUpdated`

Comment: check the answer @Qadeer

Answer (score 1):

well since you have

```
public ActionResult DealProducts(FormCollection form)
{
   TempData["check"] = "DealUpdated";
}
```

shouldn't you have

```
public ActionResult CustomizedBudget()
{
   var temp = TempData["check"];
   var temp = TempData["check"].Key;//like this
   if (temp.Count > 0) // or trying to get like this, but not  
}
```

?

Comment: where to get the Value of my TempData `DealUpdated`

Answer (score 1):

you need to change in below Action

```
public ActionResult CustomizedBudget() 
{ var temp = TempData["check"]; }
```

Comment: where to get the Value of my TempData `DealUpdated`

Comment: Value in temp variable